# How could the answer is 3? Isn't supposed to be 7 because there are 7 items in the list?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, count

The following function returns 3? Why? The number of items in the list is 7. Please help me everyone. Thank you.

```
def my_fun(x):
    z = 0
    for item in x:
        m = x.count(item)
        if m > z:
            z = m
    return z

y = ["cat", 4, "dog" , "cat" , 2, "cat", 2]
print (my_fun(y))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  refer this bfore asking a query

Answer (score 3):

This code is iterating through the elements and counting how many times each element appears.  "cat" appears three times, and that is more than any other element appears, so it returns 3.